# BibTex MWE is not working

Tags: bibtex, xetex, pdftex, texstudio

When i'm trying to execute this code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{trial.bib}
    @article{paper,
    author={name},
    title="{title}",
    journal={J. Phys. Conf. Ser.},
    volume={67},
    number={},
    pages={23},
    year={2007}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\title{Autumn Term Report}
\author{myself}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

HI \cite{paper}

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{trial}
\end{document}
```

I get the following:

[image]

I can not understand why my BibTex does not work. I'm using TeXstudio and tried to execute that by XeLaTeX and PdfLaTeX compilers.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you explicitly run bibtex? In addition to pdflatex/xelatex

Comment: Does this answer help you? [Question mark instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63875/105447)

Comment: @DaiBowen, no, [i just put this line in the settings of IDE](https://i.imgur.com/srscCI6.png).

Comment: Bibtex is a separate tool which must be run independently to latex .  In order to get citations working it is necessary to run `(pdf/xe)latex bibtex (pdf/xe)latex (pdf/xe)latex`

Comment: This sequence of commands described by DaiBowen is probably set in TeXStudio's "Build & View" command. But they can also be independently accessed through the "Tools" menu.

Comment: I have no problem running your code in texstudio. Go to `options > configure texstudio > generate` and check that you are using bibtex and not biber. I use biblatex and biber as a standard, which gave me the same result as in your picture. When I changed to bibtex, it compiled neatly.

Comment: I just switched back to biber and it gives me question marks again, omitting the references-section altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to you all, i just did not used to compile bibliography separately. F8 before compilation is helped (or `Tools->Bibliography`).